# React useState doesn't persist in created context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

From my understanding when I create a context with initialized state value, the state should persist. However, from my observation everytime I call `setValue` a new state is created with new initialized value.

For following code I would expect `Test` class constructor to be called just once, but its called each time I call `setValue`

```js
import { createContext, FunctionComponent, useContext, useState } from "react";

const Context = createContext<any>(null as any);

class Test {
  constructor() {
    console.log("test created");
  }
}

const ContextProvider: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    test: new Test(),
    update // eslint-disable-line
  });
  function update(data: any) {
    setValue({ ...value, ...data });
  }
  return <Context.Provider value={value}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};

const Child = () => {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  return <button onClick={() => context.update({ text: "hi" })}>update</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  console.log("render app");
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Child />
      </div>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Each time when button "update" is clicked, a new Test is created.
Here is the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-issue-jjwtg?file=/src/App.tsx

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because each render has its own props and state. When you call setValue, it triggers a rerender of your component. The next render will the run your code again, and the compare any differences, in order to figure out how to update the DOM.

Since you don't intend on the Test being initialized on every render, you can pass a callback function to the useState function, which React will run to get the initial state. Like so:

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => ({
    test: new Test(),
    update // eslint-disable-line
  }));
```

If you want to read more about this kind of stuff, I highly recommend reading this blog post by Dan Abramov https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-props-and-state

Answer (score 1):

Objects are reference types so each time you call setValue, a new object is created. So every time object will be different and it will call new Test()

Answer (score 1):

First, this has nothing to do with React Context, it's more of how objects/functions references are created and used in javascript.

By default, whenever there's a state change, your component is re-rendered (ie. the function is re-executed) and all local variables and inner functions are reinitialized except state values.

So, every time `setValue` is called, a new instance reference of `test` is created, thereby causing the `Test` class to be reinitialized accordingly.

To avoid this, you can wrap the `test` initialization with a [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook

Like this:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState({
  test: useCallback(() => new Test(), []),
  update // eslint-disable-line
});
```

The `useCallback` hook will return memoized version of the test instance preventing it from being reinitialized at every state update.